# How to convert pandas column of numpy.int64 variables to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have imported a dataset that has a column called `YR--MODAHRMN` that has dates formatted like this:

`201008010051`

They type is `numpy.int64` and I can't figure out how to convert to datetime.

If I do:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YR--MODAHRMN'])
```

it gives me a column of all Jan 1, 1970 12:03 AM

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YR--MODAHRMN'], format='%Y-%m%d$H%M')`?

Comment: I get ValueError: time data 201008010051 does not match format '%Y-%m%d$H%M' (match). It also doesn't work doing format='%Y%m%d$H%M

Comment: My bad, should be `format='%Y%m%d$H%M'`, no dash.

Comment: I also tried converting to a string but I get the same error ValueError: time data '201008010051' does not match format '%Y%m%d$H%M' (match)

Comment: Yea I tried without the dash but still doesn't work... not sure why

Comment: How did a `$` get in the format is beyond my knowledge. Try this for the last time `format='%Y%m%d%H%M'`.

Comment: Ha! Totally missed that too. Ok so new error now... AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from %r, try using the 'ambiguous' argument

Answer (score 0):

try these
`pd.to_datetime(df['YR--MODAHRMN'].apply(str))`

or

`pd.to_datetime(df['YR--MODAHRMN'].apply(lambda x:str(x)))`

Comment: Thanks - that works but now I get:

AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from %r, try using the 'ambiguous' argument

Comment: I didn't get your new error, could you please give a piece of code to reproduce the error?

Comment: Tried replicating on a small section of the dataset and it worked. So it must be some value in the dataset that is causing the ambiguous time error. I can make it work if I pass utc=True. And then I fix the timezone later.

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YR--MODAHRMN'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M', utc=True)